# How to Schedule Task using Marklogic

Tags: scheduler, marklogic

These are following areas where Scheduling Task Using Marklogic can be used

1.Loading content. For example, periodically checking for new content from an   external data source, such as a web site, web service, etc.

2.Synchronizing content. For example, when MarkLogic is used as a metadata repository, you might want to periodically check for changed data.

3.Delivering batches of content: For example, initiate an RSS feed, hourly or daily.

4.Delivering aggregated alerts, either hourly or daily.

5.Delivering reports, either daily, weekly, or monthly.

6.Polling for the completion of an asynchronous process, such as the creation of a PDF file

My requirement is to schedule a task for bulk loading data from local file system to Marklogic DB using any data loading option available in Marklogic such as 
1.MLCP 
2.Xquery 
3.Rest API 
4.Java API 
5.WebDAV.

So is there any option to execute this programatically. I prefer MLCP since I need to perform bulk load of data from local file system

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute MLCP Content Load Command as a schedule task in Marklogic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696689/execute-mlcp-content-load-command-as-a-schedule-task-in-marklogic)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your question at [Execute MLCP Content Load Command as a schedule task in Marklogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696689/execute-mlcp-content-load-command-as-a-schedule-task-in-marklogic) , I would start with a tool like Apache Camel. There are other options - Mule, Spring Integration, and plenty of commercial/graphical ETL tools - but I've found Camel to be very easy to get started with, and you can utilize the mlcp Camel component at https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-camel-mlcp .

Comment: Then how is it possible to perfrom the following functionality using Marklogic Task sceduler for bulk load of content which is mentioned i their documentation https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/scheduling_tasks        Loading content. For example, periodically checking for new content from an external data source, such as a web site, web service, etc

Comment: What I need to perform is a bulk load of data in to Marklogic Database from my external file system in my local PC using MLCP[Marklogic Content Pump]. Can this be done as a scheduled task using Marklogic Task Scheduler

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you may be able to use https://developer.marklogic.com/code/mljam to allow for an XQuery module, invoked as a scheduled task, to run mlcp. How much content do you have to load from your PC on a regular basis? You may not need mlcp - if you're loading something on the order of thousands of documents, you can probably get that done in a single transaction in your XQuery/JS module that's invoked as a scheduled task. I just think in this kind of a scenario, I want to use mlcp, and to me, the easiest way to use mlcp on a scheduled basis is via a tool like Camel.